# How would you implement a fast algorithm to calculate the sum of graph distance/Euclidean distance from each node to all other nodes in graph-tools

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-tool

I am trying to implement straightness centrality, as defined in this document as equation six (http://udsu-strath.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/PA2006_06new1.pdf) as a node's centrality determined by the sum of the the Eucledean distance divided by the graph distance between that node and all other nodes divided by 1/(N-1);

I have a graph of about 60,000 nodes; I tried iterating through it and using dask to parallalize it but that doesn't really cut any order off big O;

I've have it implemented by storing the x/y coordinates of each node in a dictionary with the key as the node number that can be accessed easily, but I am not too skilled at solving these sort of algorithm optimisation problems.

Like graph-tools have OpenMP Support, but I am not very sure how to write an algorithm to leverage that.

This is my current attempt

```
#too slow

def euclidean_dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

def bravo(target, n, vertID_dict_scattered, network_dist):
    euclidean_distance = euclidean_dist(vertID_dict_scattered[n][0], vertID_dict_scattered[n][1], vertID_dict_scattered[target][0], vertID_dict_scattered[target][1])
    return euclidean_distance / network_dist

@dask.delayed
def alpha(G, n, vertID_dict_scattered):
    straightness = 0
    sp = gt.shortest_distance(G, n, weights=G.edge_properties["mm_len"])
    sp_scattered = sp

    if len(sp.get_array()) > 0 and len(G) > 1:
        for target, value in enumerate(sp):
            if n != target:
                network_dist = sp_scattered[target]
                straightness += bravo(target, n, vertID_dict_scattered, network_dist)
        straightness_df = straightness * (1.0 / (len(vertID_dict_scattered.keys()) - 1.0))
    else:
        straightness_df = 0
    
    return n, straightness_df

def split_list(lst, chunk_size):
    return [lst[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(lst), chunk_size)]\
        
def straightness_centrality(G, vertID_dict):
    
    # chunked_list = split_list(list(G.iter_vertices()), 32)
    # G_scattered = client.scatter(G)
    # vertID_dict_scattered = client.scatter(vertID_dict)
    # result=[]
    
    # for chunk in chunked_list:   
    #     delayed_objs = [alpha(G_scattered, n, vertID_dict_scattered) for n in chunk]
    #     new_results = client.compute(delayed_objs)
        # result.append(new_results)
    
    
    chunked_list = split_list(list(G.iter_vertices()), 32)
    G_scattered = client.scatter(G)
    vertID_dict_scattered = client.scatter(vertID_dict)
    results=[]

    for chunk in chunked_list:   
        delayed_objs = [alpha(G_scattered, n, vertID_dict_scattered) for n in chunk]
        new_results = client.compute(delayed_objs)
        gathered_results = client.gather(new_results)
        results.append(gathered_results)
        
    return results

straightness_df = straightness_centrality(gtG, vertID_dict)
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a small example graph? Just something to plug into your above algorithm to see it run

Comment: What's the big-O of your code? Calculating all fo the euclidean distances is O(n^2), so if your code is also n^2, then there are no big O gains to be had, merely optimizations.

Comment: You seem to care about performance, but you do not say how long your code takes on a 60,000 node network, nor do you say what your target performance is.

Comment: Sorry - I am not particularly savvy to this side of computer science so not sure what exactly needed to be posted; taking about a minute to run will be good; as of now it will take literally days on my Ryzen 7 3700X

Comment: @Reuben "[...] not sure what exactly needed to be posted" - please post a complete example. We currently cannot run your code as-is, because its missing imports and we don't have the `gtG` and `vertID_dict`.  If we can't run your code, it makes it much less likely that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @MooingDuck the time spent calculating euclidean distances is going to be trumped by the time spent calculating the shortest path lengths. The latter is O(N^3) (ford-warshall) for dense graphs, and O(N^2logN)` (dijkstra's) for sparse graphs, neither of which is easy to vectorize, unlike the distance computation.

Comment: After a bit of googling, it seems that graph-tools has OpenMP support baked in, it just needs to be compiled with it enabled. At runtime, you specify the number of threads, and it just works- if the algorithm is parallelizable, it will run across multiple threads.

Comment: @DillonDavis: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668702/shortest-distance-between-all-pairs-of-nodes-in-graph For undirected graphs with nonnegative integer edge weights: [Thorup](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/316542.316548), iterated over each vertex, has (). "" and "" denote the number of vertices and number of edges, respectively.

Comment: @MooingDuck I may be misunderstanding, but that seems to tackle the problem of finding the shortest paths from a single source vertex. Repeating for all vertices, the time then becomes O(EV^2).